# why does DOMDocument turn UTF-8 encoded umlauts into numeric entities?

Tags: php, xml, utf-8, domdocument

If I output the string before adding it as a text node to the DOMDocument tree then I can see that the original UTF-8 encoding is preserved. All umlauts are UTF-8 encoded - for sure.

Then I add the string and output the DOM-tree-object through saveXML() and all umlauts have been replaced by their respective numerical entity.

I create the DOMDocument like this: `$xmlDoc = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');`

Shouldn't XML then keep all UTF-8 encoded chars alone as long as they aren't XML-special chars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that this is a bug. [`DOMDocument::loadXML()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) simply seems to override the internal version and encoding settings with the ones detected in the given XML string - actually overriding everything that has been set in the [`DOMDocument` constructor](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php).

```
$d = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$d->loadXML('<root><node/></root>');
var_dump(array(
    'encoding' => $d->encoding, // NULL
    'version'    => $d->xmlVersion // 1.0
));
$d->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><root><node/></root>');
var_dump(array(
    'encoding' => $d->encoding, // ISO-8859-1
    'version'    => $d->xmlVersion // 1.0
));
```

So if you're using [`DOMDocument::loadXML()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) you have to ensure that the XML string contains a valid XML declaration.
The constructor arguments are used when you built the document from scratch.